# Jplayer não funciona no IE8

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

Tenho uma listagem de áudio em uma página que estou desenvolvendo, no Mozilla e Chrome, IE9 e IE10 ficou show de bola, porém no IE8, ele não executa quando aperto o botão 'play'.

Site do Jplayer: http://jplayer.org/

Alguém já passou por esse problema com funcionamento no IE8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De forma simples, o IE8 não suporta o elemento `<audio>` do HTML5. Ele foi introduzido a partir do IE9.

Veja aqui a tabela de suporte: [**Can I use Audio?**](http://caniuse.com/audio)

Na página da biblioteca: http://jplayer.org/HTML5.Audio.Support/

> **Internet Explorer 8:** No Support for audio

Comment: Olá, eu li isso. Porém, não lembro de ter usado o elemento <audio> no PHP. Aqui esta o meu código: http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/y2vRu/

Comment: A jPlayer usa o <audio> internamente para produzir o som. Ela deve inserir o elemento no documento por você.

Comment: Ahhhh, entendi =/ Existe alguma forma de fazer ele comportar? algum plugin? Tipo, esses dias tive problema com o @media do CSS e encontrei um plugin para o mesmo.

Comment: Acredito que uma solução perfeitamente aceitável seria apontar seus usuários para [whatbrowser.org](http://whatbrowser.org/). De outra maneira, pode tentar manipular audios via flash, applet de java ou algo relacionado a activex. Desconheço uma solução direta.

Comment: Vou ter que fazer uma condição, se o usuário tiver IE8, ele executa o flash, ao invés do HTML5.